Riesz representation theorem & the orthogonal projection.
Here is the question I am thinking of:
Suppose $U$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $V$ and $v \in V.$ Define a linear functional $\phi : U \to F$ by $$\phi (u) = \langle u, v \rangle$$ for all $u \in U.$ By the Riesz representation theorem $(6.42)$ as applied to the inner product space $U,$ there exists a unique vector $w \in U$ such that $$\phi(u) = \langle u,w \rangle$$ for all $u \in U.$ Show that $w = P_U v.$
Here is my definition to the orthogonal projection:
Suppose $U$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $V.$ The orthogonal projection of $V$ onto $U$ is the operator $P_U \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ defined as follows:
For $v \in V,$ write $v = u + w,$ where $u \in U$ and $w \in U^{\perp}.$ Then $P_Uv = u.$
I am not sure though how to prove that $w = P_U v$ though. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

By definition
$$\phi(u)=\langle u,v\rangle=\langle u,v-P_Uv+P_Uv\rangle=\langle u,v-P_Uv\rangle+\langle u,P_Uv\rangle$$
for all $u\in U$. But $v-P_Uv\in U^{\perp}$, so the first term vanishes, and we get
$$\phi(u)=\langle u,P_Uv\rangle.$$
But $P_Uv\in U$, and as $w$ was the unique element in $U$ with the above property, it follows that $w=P_Uv$.
